# MySQL and phpMyAdmin: display transformation

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have some binary and boolean columns which I would like to display in a human readable format. Ex:

1. boolean as T/F
2. binary as IPv4/IPv6
3. binary (file hash) as base64url

It seems that this could be done in phpMyAdmin via 'browser display transformation'.
Items 1&2 could be done via built-in transformations ('Bool2Text' and 'Binarytoip') while item 3 would require a custom transformation.

Unfortunately, both 'Bool2Text' and 'Binarytoip' did not worked. It seems to be disabled.

**Questions**

1. How to enable 'browser display transformation' in phpMyAdmin? I have already read the [documentation](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/transformations.html) but still could not make it.
2. How to make a custom 'browser display transformation' in phpMyAdmin? Specifically display binary as base64url (item 3).
3. Is it possible to do the same in MySQL CLI?